# Height of TButton with Multiline caption does not fit its caption-text

Tags: delphi, multiline, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 Win32 VCL Application on Windows 10, I have a `TButton` with `WordWrap = True` and `Caption = 'SAVE TO INTERNET BOOKMARKS FOLDER...'`:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the height of the button does not automatically fit its `Caption` text.

Is there a feature in `TButton` to achieve this automatically, or do I have to adjust this manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no automatic adjustment of the height of a `TButton` offered by the VCL.

If you change the font of the button's caption, or make it multi-line, you typically have to adjust the button's height yourself explicitly.

As a comparison, `TEdit` does have an `AutoSize` property. This doesn't map to a feature of the Win32 EDIT control (like a [window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles)), but is implemented purely in the VCL (see `Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.AdjustHeight()`).

However, I just discovered that the underlying Win32 BUTTON control does offer this functionality, via the [`BCM_GETIDEALSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcm-getidealsize) message or [`Button_GetIdealSize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-button_getidealsize) macro:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Winapi.CommCtrl;

var
  S: TSize;
begin
  S.cx := Button1.Width;
  if Button_GetIdealSize(Button1.Handle, S) then
    Button1.Height := S.cy;
```

This will set the height given the button's current text and desired width. If `S` is initially zeros, you get the button's preferred width and height.

It is not uncommon that a Win32 control offers more functionality than its VCL wrapper exposes, so it is often a good idea to have a look at the Win32 documentation, particularly the [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-button-control-reference-messages) you can send to the control (and also its [styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles)).

Comment: It works perfectly! Where do you get all these "magical" solutions?

Comment: @user1580348: I added that to the A.

Comment: Just looking at available styles and their documentation I use button-like checkboxes for decades already: `SetWindowLong( checkbox.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong( checkbox.Handle, GWL_STYLE ) or BS_PUSHLIKE );` - makes a great "run/stop" button.

Comment: BTW, here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/c8J6kAc.png

Comment: @AmigoJack It would be nice if it would keep the check glyph: https://i.imgur.com/Bjf7guZ.png

Comment: @user1580348 I totally expected that outcome and will continue using it for selected occasions - of course I'm not using it for _every_ checkbox (but instead for occasions where a button alone would not be enough).